# Проблема с разрешением Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Всем привет!
Сегодня поставил Ubuntu LTS 20.10.
Сначала после установки был черный экран, из-за чего всегда приходится лезть в grub панель и изменять конфиг запуска.

Главная проблема: Никак не ставится разрешение выше 1024х768. Пытался ставить через xrandr/cvt - не работает, моментально возвращает на 1024х768, монитор от LG (Full HD), подключение по VGA, в xrandr --verbose отображается как default, монитор не определяется, на Windows Full hd разрешение чудесно работает, а монитор определяется.

Вот ответ xrandr в терминале:

root@Denys-pc:/home # xrandr

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1024x768      76.00*

Comment: Банально драйвер для видеокарты забыли установить наверное?

Comment: Прописывал sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall, пишет нет драйверов для установки

Comment: 1. Что конкретно вы вписали в настроки grub? 2. Можно скрин вкладки "Драйверы" из `software-properties-gtk`?

Comment: 1. Для загрузки в Ubuntu приходится в grub меню выбирать ubuntu, нажимать e, и заменить строку ro quiet splash на nomodeset quiet splash 2. Нет вкладки "Драйверы", только "Дополнительные драйверы", также окно полностью в экран не вмещается, скрин http://yapx.ru/v/L7XN7

Comment: Хмм, а можно еще скрин самой первой вкладки?

Comment: http://yapx.ru/v/L7YBi

Comment: А скажите, какая у вас видеокарта? Можно еще попробовать полистать `journalctl -b0` на предмет какой-нибудь ругани на видеокарту.

Comment: Видеокарта интегрированная AMD Radeon R7 Graphics на 1гб, процессор AMD A8-7680 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G, ОЗУ DDR 3 16 гб

Comment: Ответ journalctl -b0: https://pastebin.com/P1yd2D5j

Comment: Тогда такая идея: поставьте себе программу для удаленного доступа (проще всего Anydesk). Уберите из grub-а `nomodeset`. Включите комп, подключитесь удаленно, и посмотрите в настройки дисплея. Возможно там разблокируются другие разрешения. Вангую, что черный экран потому, что там стоит какой-то параметр, который ваш моник не поддерживает, типа частота > 60 гц. Если этот параметр исправить, должно заработать без nomodeset.

Comment: Еще, когда отвечаете, пишите в начале `@username`, а то мне уведомления не приходят.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, после запуска видно чёрный экран, при попытке подключения пишет "Remote Display server is not supported (e. g. Wayland)", при запуске с nomodeset подключается.

Comment: Видимо не угадал. А покажите вывод `journalctl -b-1`. (Он печатает логи *предыдущего* включения компьютера. Убедитесь, что предыдущее включение было без `nomodeset`.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ответ journalctl -b-1: https://pastebin.com/tSXL38KT